# How to subset a vector by another vector?

Tags: r, subset

Given this

```
data <- list(a=c(1,3,5), b=c(3,4,7,4,8,6), c=c(3,4,8,3,4,8,0))
sample <- c(4,8)
```

Is there any way to retrieve the list members that contain the sequence `c(4,8)`?

In this case, that would be `data$b` and `data$c`.

Comment: Would `c(8,4)`, `c(4,0,8)`, etc. count too?

Comment: So you want to check list members which have 4 and 8 as consecutive elements, or is the position irrelevant?

Comment: @Julius No, it should be in the same order.

Comment: @TejaK I would like to check the ones that have 4 and 8 as consecutive elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would return a logical vector suitable for selection of items from the list-`data`:

```
sapply(data, function(x) any(
                              intersect( which( x==sample[1]), # check for first value
     # then see if any of those locations also have successive differences are the same as in the `sample` item.
                                         which( diff(x) == diff(sample) ))  ))

$a
[1] FALSE

$b
[1] TRUE

$c
[1] TRUE
```

Illustration:

```
 data[ sapply(data, function(x) any( intersect(  which( x==sample[1]), 
                                               which( diff(x) == diff(sample) )) ) )
     ]
#----------
$b
[1] 3 4 7 4 8 6

$c
[1] 3 4 8 3 4 8 0
```

Comment: Does this code on work if the "sample" vector has more elements? @42-

Answer (score 3):

```
data[grep(paste0(c("", sample, ""), collapse = "_"), 
      paste0("_", sapply(data, paste0, collapse = "_"), "_"))]
# $b
# [1] 3 4 7 4 8 6
# 
# $c
# [1] 3 4 8 3 4 8 0
```

Comment: Thank you, works beautifully. Would you mind explaining how this works? Or is this not the place to ask that? @Julius

Comment: Using a length zero collapse-string means you might match a vector with `48` or a sequence with `34,81`. Safer would be to use a `"_"` and also paste "_" to the end to the 'sample' item.

Comment: @mousadafousa, in any case it is useful to try and see what each piece of this line does. 1) `paste0(sample, collapse = "")` gives `"48"`, 2) `sapply(data, paste0, collapse = "")` gives a character vector with elements like `"135"`. Then `grep` checks in which elements of this vector there is a string `"48"` and returns their indices.

Comment: OK, you accepted half of my suggestion but still has potential for "false postive with c(34, 82) anywhere in the sequence. Need first argument to be `paste(paste0(sample, collapse = "_"), "_")`

Comment: @julius I see, that makes sense. Thank you for outlining that.

Comment: And I now think that also need to put a "_" before both the sample and hte data arguments to avoid errors with `c(44, 8)`